# making one sided thesis in latex

Tags: page-numbering

I am writing my thesis. I want everything on even numbered pages( right side of the book). I am not getting it. I am using

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epsfig,color}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{latexsym,amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage[space]{cite}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-30pt} %we cannot put this restriction -15
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-25pt}
\addtolength{\evensidemargin}{-100pt}  %-70pt
\addtolength{\textwidth}{111pt}
\addtolength{\textheight}{136pt} %we cannot put this restr
\let\cleardoublepage\clearpage
\date{}
```

please help.

Comment: I think the oneside option thinks of every page as an odd page. This only affects the margin spacing and does not insert a blank page between every pair of consecutive pages. You get a one-sided document when you print it.

Comment: Can you please clarify? You want the first page to be number 2, the following number 4 and so on?

Comment: Seriously, you can manipulate the header and \marginpar directly to make every page ACT like an even page.

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust the even page margins while ignoring the odd page margins, as there will be no odd pages.  Note: one could instead use the everypage package, but it would be executed AFTER the page is laid out, whereas `\afterpage` is executed BEFORE the next page is laid out.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\fudgeit}{\stepcounter{page}\afterpage{\fudgeit}}
\AtBeginDocument{\fudgeit}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```